# Elasticsearch function_score with nested_objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with a query.I used a query for boosting documents with no nested_objects. Now i use nested_objects and changed the query to use a nested filter but nothing is boosted.
I get the documents i expected but with no _score changes.

Am i doing something wrong ??

```
GET index/type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "parent.child": "test"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "functions": [
            {
               "boost_factor": "100",
               "filter": {
                  "nested": {
                     "path": "parent",
                     "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                           "must": [
                              {
                                 "term": {
                                    "child": "test"
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "score_mode": "sum"
      }
   },
   "sort": "_score",
   "from": 0,
   "size": 320
}
```

EDIT:
Could it be caused by

> nested filter
>
> A nested filter behaves much like a nested query, except that it
>   doesn’t accept the score_mode parameter. It can only be used in
>   “filter context” — such as inside a filtered query —  and it behaves
>   like any other filter: it includes or excludes, but it doesn’t score.
>
> While the results of the nested filter itself are not cached, the
>   usual caching rules apply to the filter inside the nested filter.
>
> http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says:

nested filter

A nested filter behaves much like a nested query, except that it doesn’t accept the score_mode parameter. It can only be used in “filter context” — such as inside a filtered query —  and it behaves like any other filter: it includes or excludes, but **it doesn’t score**.

While the results of the nested filter itself are not cached, the usual caching rules apply to the filter inside the nested filter.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling your JSON should look closer this (maybe not exactly though, I havent tested it).

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {
           "nested": {
               "path": "parent",
               "query": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "parent.child": "test"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "functions": [
            {
               "boost_factor": "100"
            }
         ],
         "score_mode": "sum"
      }
   },
   "sort": "_score",
   "from": 0,
   "size": 320
}
```

Specifically, you dont want to filter the `boost_factor`, you just want to boost this `function_score` by 100. The actual nested query though goes in the `query` section of the `function_score`, and the `functions` section just contains the `boost_factor`. I think.

Comment: The query works as expected if i remove the nested part and boost on a root field.

Comment: In the nested query, shouldnt it still be `"parent.child": "test"` and not `"child": "test"`? In terms of the actual problem, sorry, I cant actually test stuff right now :( Ill delete my answer